# Generating a link with Markdown (BlueCloth) that opens in a new window

Tags: hyperlink, markdown

I'd like to have a link generated with BlueCloth that opens in a new window. All I could find was the ordinary `[Google](http://www.google.com/)` syntax but nothing with a new window.

Ideas?

Regards

Tom

Comment: It is not a Question about BlueCloth. It is about Markdown. so please change the title.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete reference for markdown: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

And since there is no mention of how to set the target attribute, I would believe it is not directly possible, but the reference also says:

> For any markup that is not covered by
>   Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML
>   itself. There’s no need to preface it
>   or delimit it to indicate that you’re
>   switching from Markdown to HTML; you
>   just use the tags.

Source: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html

So I would suggest you have to use the html syntax for links like this

**update**

if you wrap the markdown generated content in a div with a specific id like this:

and you use jQuery, you can add the following javascript:

```
$('#some_id a').attr('target','_blank');
```

Or you can save the BlueCloth output in a variable before outputting.

```
markdown_generated_string.gsub!(/<a\s+/i,'<a target="_blank" ')
```

Comment: I am using `:escape_html => true`, so that is not possible. I don't want the user to type plain html, I wouldn't need markdown for that. :\

Comment: See my update: You can manipulate it vie javascript after rendering or via ruby before rendering.